# Column names don't auto populate on Unpivot task on Azure Data Factory Dataflow

Tags: unpivot, azure-data-factory

I'm new to ADF and trying to build a new Dataflow and have hard time connecting **Source** task to **Unpivot** task:

[image: the Select Column is expanded with "No results found"]

On **Source1**, I can see the preview of the data. Why on the "**Ungroup by**" the list of columns don't populate?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the problem is that you are using a wrong connector. You should use a connector from DataSet category and not a connector from Database category.
On the other hand, you can use the same connector (Database Query) for both Source and UnPivot task. In this case, you should select
`Use DataSet`
option in Database Query task and then use the same dataset for UnPivot task.